# I made This code to when rythm bot (other bot in my Server) join vc but it works for all user and always say joined vc

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
   if (newMember.id = "235088799074484224")
{
    let newUserChannel = "844108228353851392"

    let oldUserChannel = "844108228353851392"

    if(newUserChannel === "844108228353851392") {
        console.log("Joined VC1")

    } else if(newUserChannel !== "844108228353851392"){
        console.log("Left VC1")

    }}});
```

Comment: Might your condition not work becuase here should put === not = .
if (newMember.id = "235088799074484224")

Comment: = is used to assignement and ===  or == used for comparision.

Comment: This is caused by a typo, as mentioned above. `.id = ...` should be `.id == ...` (or better yet, `.id === ...`) Add a linter to your development environment to catch this stuff.

Comment: only showing left vc and log on all member join

Comment: @AKX it is now only saying joined vc

Comment: @Lol If you updated your code into the question, it still has the same typo in the first `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be done like this -

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
   if (newState.member.id === "235088799074484224"){
     if (newState.channelID === null) {
          console.log("Joined VC!")
     }
     else if (oldState.channelID === null) {
         console.log("Left VC!")
     }
   }
});
```

This will detect if the user with the specific id joins and leaves the vc.

Answer (score 0):

The above anwser of max is having mistake so the correct should be.

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
   if (newState.member.id === "235088799074484224"){
     if (newState.channelID === null) {
         // When you left VC new channel id will be null
         console.log("Left VC!")
     } else{
         console.log("User Joined or Switch Channel)
     }
   }
});
```